# how to install adobe air in android emulator

Tags: android, apache-flex, adobe, air

i am implementing one application related to android in adobe flex, .apk is generated and now while installing the .apk file in emulator, emulator is showing one pop up to install adobe air, while again installing on adobe air , it is showing that no mobile device is connected to you system. so how can i install adobe air in emulator to test the application made in adobe flex?

thanks in advance 
Narasimha

Comment: install runtime.apk in emulator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install the AIR runtime on the emulator:

adb -e install -r Runtime_Emulator_Froyo_20100930.apk

from this site:
http://flashsimulations.com/2010/10/19/developing-android-applications-with-adobe-air/

Comment: Take the time to look at the link provided by Dr.nik, Mr. narashimha. Whatever questions you have they're all answered there.

Comment: one more thing i want to know that when you run in mobile it cant but if you use adobe flash player  then it will.so install first in device  and run

Answer (score 3):

Download the Adobe Flex SDK and get the AIR "Runtime.apk" file from "runtimes/air/android/emulator/"